# Spark RDD take() with Sequence File

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, sequencefile

It looks like `RDD.take()` just repeats the last element read when backed by a SequenceFile.
For instance:

```
val rdd = sc.sequenceFile("records.seq", classOf[LongWritable], classOf[RecordWritable])
val records: Array[(LongWritable, RecordWritable)] = rdd.take(5)
System.out.println(records.map(_._2.toString).mkString("\n"))
```

Outputs:

```
Record(3.1, 2.5)
Record(3.1, 2.5)
Record(3.1, 2.5)
Record(3.1, 2.5)
Record(3.1, 2.5)
```

Even though I know the rows are unique.

This problem is also present for `sc.binaryRecords()`.

I realize this is probably related to the Hadoop Writable caching issue, but are there any plans to fix this?  Are there any work-arounds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried replicate your issue and Yes, I also saw similar behavior when calling **take** directly on the result of **sc.sequenceFile()**. But was able to find work around:

*Note: I am explaining using LongWritable and Text instead of RecordWritable. I am not sure of the import needed for RecordWritable*

 My sequence file is having:`(0,0) (1,1) (2,2) ...`

```
val rdd = sc.sequenceFile("sequencefile.seq", classOf[LongWritable], classOf[Text])
val map = rdd.map(case (k,v) => (k.get(),v.toString()))
map.take(1);
res5: Array[(Long, String)] = Array((0,0))
map.take(5);
res4: Array[(Long, String)] = Array((0,0), (1,1), (2,2), (3,3), (4,4))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Here's the jira item in Spark. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-1018  Looks like it also impacts collect():